# What do we call a picture of a picture?

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word for a picture of a picture? Had a search on onelook but couldn't find anything...

edit: sorry maybe I wasn't *that* clear the first time -- I mean like a photograph of a photograph...

Comment: Ceçi n'est pas une pipe.

Comment: When you say "I mean like a photograph" are you saying then it could be *"a painting of a painting"*, *"a drawing of a drawing"* etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are we talking about here? It seems to me it could be one of three things:

1. A printed copy of an original. That would be referred to as a 'print' e.g. 'An L.S. Lowry print'
2. A photograph of a picture. The best term seems to me 'Photo of the *Mona Lisa*'
3. If you are talking about another artist's copy then I think you would say 'another artists copy of *The Last Supper*

Comment: There's also "fine art reproduction" or "a reproduction of The Last Supper" basically a euphemism for saying a fake painting.

Comment: Isn't the painting of a picture called a replica?

Comment: @RenaeLider You may well be right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, you are quite right - a *reproduction*. It took an Italian to get it right for me.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you were talking about when you see the same picture within a picture within a picture over and over, and I wondered the same thing, so I found this on Wikipedia.

“In Western art history, Mise en abyme...is a formal technique of placing a copy of an image within itself, often in a way that suggests an infinitely recurring sequence. In film theory and literary theory, it refers to the technique of inserting a story within a story. The term is derived from heraldry and literally means ‘placed into abyss.’“

also google “Droste effect” for a modern example.

Comment: But OP has clearly indicated that this isn't what they meant.